# Why can't I research any more caps or cores?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

I have researched all the Wand Foci that directly connects to the Wand Foci research, Gold and Copper Caps and Greatwood Wand Cores but I can't research the next cap or wand core that's directly connected.

I've also researched these 2 Node Stabilizers and some Node Relay which were in the upper left corner however I am unsure if they were added by an add-on since they were hidden away.

I want to know how I can research the next cap and core as currently they remained grayed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This forum post](http://forum.feed-the-beast.com/threads/1-6-x-thaumcraft-4-0-5b-research-cheat-sheet-1mil-views-topic-above-me-is-a-doodoo-head-ha.32560/) has a basic rundown of all the required research for the Thaumcraft 4 mod. Basically, a lot of the new wands require a new strain of research (pages added to the Thauminomicon) before you can unlock new recipes for crafting/infusion.

For example, the next wand cap - Tahumium Wand Caps requires:

- Research: Instrumentum - Metallum - Praecantatio
- Required Research: Gold Wand Caps - Thaumium - Infusion

the next wand - Bone Wand Core requires:

- Research: Exanimis - Instrumentum - Praecantatio - Perditio
- Required Research: Greatwood Wand Core - Infusion

Comment: I don't think i've seen Infusion on the Thaumaturgy page, where about's is it?

Comment: I believe it would be referring to the Infusion altar.